# R: Change multiple strings to one other string

Tags: r

Relative R newbie here. How do I change multiple strings to one string in a character vector?

For example:

```
college <- c("CAS", "HHS", "CB", "CAS,HHS", "CB", "CAS,CB", "CAS,HHS,CB", "HHS")
```

I want to keep "CAS", "HHS", and "CB", and change everything else to "MULT".
I've tried:

```
dontchange <- c("CAS", "HHS", "CB")
college[college!=dontchange] <- c("MULT")
college
[1] "CAS"  "HHS"  "CB"   "MULT" "MULT" "MULT" "MULT" "HHS"
```

The fifth element (second "MULT") should be CB.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430698/12158757) has explained in every bit regarding `!=` and `%in%`.

Here are some option that may help

```
replace(college, !college %in% dontchange, "MULT")
```

or

```
replace(college, is.na(match(college, dontchange)), "MULT")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `!=`, use `%in%` with `!`.  The elementwise comparison operators like `==` or `!=` recycle the second vector to make the length same while doing the comparison i.e. the elements in 'dontchange' are recycled from the beginning until it reaches the end of the first string

```
college[!college %in% dontchange] <- "MULT"
```

---

```
college != dontchange
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

> Warning message:
> In college != dontchange :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

It is similar to replicating the dontchange vector

```
rep(dontchange, length.out = length(college))
#[1] "CAS" "HHS" "CB"  "CAS" "HHS" "CB"  "CAS" "HHS"
```

Note how the values are recycled.  These are the ones getting compared for each element of the longer vector 'college'

```
college != rep(dontchange, length.out = length(college))
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

So, when we assign, it is assigning those TRUE elements in 'college' to "MULT" which is not correct.  Instead, it would be

```
!college %in% dontchange
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Another option is also `fct_collapse` from `forcats`

```
library(forcats)
fct_collapse(college, MULT = setdiff(college, dontchange))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes sense.